# Parallel Matrix Multiplication using TPL

Tags: c++, multithreading, matrix, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Of the different ways to implement matrix multiplication code in TPL using Parallel.For, what will provide better speedup of the following schemes (assume you have an 8-core machine and matrix size to be multiplied is at least 5000x5000). 
1. Only the outer loop i is implemented as Parallel.For.
2. Only the inner loop k is implement as Parallel.For.
3. All three loops i, j, k are implemented as Parallel.For.

Code:

```
Parallel.For (0, n, i =>
{
   for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
   {
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
      C[i, j] += A[i, k] * B[k, j];
   }
});
```

Comment: You could add patchin algorithm so it fits in cache, works wwell with high order Strassen's algorithm but is some lossy. Otherwise, only a gpu(with equal cost$ of that cpu) can get under 0.1 sec per multiplication of 5kx5k

Comment: Call BLAS DGEMM. Will outperform loops by as much as 1000x.